# Linked list using Class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, linked-list

I have a code, which seems to be working but I am failing to get the values stored in the linked list between the first and the last node, the pointers in between are skipped? And dereferencing these skipped pointer gives me a segfault, here is the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include <new>
using namespace std;

class list{ 
    int value;
    list* next;

public:    
    list(int a=0, list* b=0) {value=a;next=b;}    
    //~list() {delete next;}
    void newnode(int a, list* tmp) {
        tmp->next=new list;
        tmp=tmp->next;
        cout<<"Address of next: "<<tmp<<'\n';
        tmp->value=a;
    }

    void printlist (list* regist){
        list* tmp;
        tmp=regist; 
        cout<<tmp->value<<'\n';

        while(tmp->next != 0){
            tmp=tmp->next;
            cout<<tmp->value<<'\n';
            cout<<"Address of next: "<<tmp<<'\n';   
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    int first;    
    cout<<"Enter value for origin: \n";
    cin>>first; 
    list* root=new list(first);
    list* tpo=root;
    cout<<"How many numbers to add? \n";

    int choice;
    cin>>choice;

    int num;
    while(choice) {
        cout<<"Enter value: \n";
        cin>>num;    
        root->newnode(num, tpo);
        choice--;  
    }

    cout<<"Do you want me to show you these values, type 1 for yes and 0 for no: \n";
    cin>>choice;

    if(choice) {
        root->printlist(root);
    }
}
```

1. On printing the values why does it skip these pointer(nodes) in between?
2. Are the in between nodes being pointed to destroyed? If so, commenting the destructor, should do the trick, right?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For one thing, you're not using consistent indentation. So no one has much chance of reading your code.

Comment: `root->newnode(num, tpo);` never updates `root` or `tpo` so each new value replaces the previous one

Comment: Thanks @FredLarson, I'll keep that into account, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You always overwrite the 2nd element in your list when you call for more values. You need to change `newnode()`'s signature to `newnode(int a, list*& tmp)`.

**Later edit:** another way would be to have the following signature `list* newnode(int a, list* tmp)` and at the end of the function you'd `return tmp;`. Then, in the main loop you'd have `tpo = root->newnode(num, tpo);`. This way `tpo` would always point to the next element.

2) Also, for freeing the memory `list`'s destructor shouldn't do anything in particular. I'd say you make a static method in your class that deletes a list. Something like this:

`public:
    static void deleteList(list*& root) 
    {
    list* tmp = root;
    while (tmp) 
    {
        tmp = root->next;
        delete root;
        root = NULL;
        root = tmp;
    }
};`

and call it like `list::deleteList(root);`

Comment: About point 1, why pass a pointer as a reference, because I thought the value can be changed either if the variable is passed as a reference or as a pointer

Comment: You need to pass the pointer by reference because you need to modify the **pointer** rather than the object that the pointer is pointing to when you do `tmp=tmp->next;`.
If you don't, `tmp` will still point to the same pointer that `tmp` was pointing to before entering the function, and I believe that you want `tmp` to point to `tmp->next`. Sheesh, I really need to improve my vocabulary :D (I've been using "point" 4 times in the last phrase)

Comment: Thank you very much, did some trials to understand what you said. Would definitely have not figured out if you hadn't mentioned it.

Answer (score 2):

you are always submitting `root` to newnode (as is was assigned to `tpo`) resulting in a list with two elements and an arbitrary number of leaked memory

Comment: I am sorry but I am relatively new to c++, but can i ask how passing an address would be leading to leaked memory?

Comment: You always overwrote the address of `tmp->next` when you did `tmp->next=new list;`. This happened because `tmp->next` would always point to the 2nd element in the list, instead of the 2nd, 3rd etc.

Comment: Thanks again, your earlier comment was extremely useful in clarifying how pointers work :), and this made more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

a comprehensive implementation of linked lists, check below link:

http://www.bitsbyta.com/2011/02/how-to-add-node-at-end-of-linked-list-c.html